# css styling of unordered list containing 5 ul's with same classnames, apply different styles to each

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
X:nth-of-type(n)

ul:nth-of-type(3) {   
border: 1px solid black;   
}  
ul:nth-of-type(3) {
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

There will be times when, rather than selecting a child, you instead need to select according to the type of element.

Imagine mark-up that contains five unordered lists. If you wanted to style only the third ul, 
and didn't have a unique id to hook into, you could use the nth-of-type(n) pseudo class. In the snippet above, only the third ul will have a border around it.

I have the above didn't work

```
dropmenu

<li class="submenu">
<ul.level2>
<li>something</li>
<li>something2</li>
</ul>

<ul.level2>
<li>something</li>
<li>something2</li>
</ul>

<ul.level2>
<li>something</li>
<li>something2</li>
</ul>
```

The list above is dynamicly generated by a php script and I can't change the class names therefore when I apply styles to the ul element ,it is the same for all.
Thanks for all help

Comment: So you mean the PHP script is adding tag names like `<ul.level2>`? That's messed up.

Answer (score 1):

Which browser are you testing this in because the pseudo-class `:nth-of-type(n)` is not supported across all browsers. For example, it is not supported in Internet Explorer.

Comment: You are correct the output is class="level2",in my css I used .level2.

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to remove the `.level2` from the ul tags and replace with `<ul class="level2">`? Then your css should work.

Comment: I will check,but how would that help to apply a different style to each?

Comment: I can do that but how can I apply different styling to ul,The menu can be viewed url www.cedlabs.com/chas/cart5

Comment: From the response I guess there is no way to use css to style each  of the ul.level2 different,I would like to thank all who did reply.I am new to this site and I hope I asked the question correctly and was clear again thanks